# how to connect d3.js with SSAS cube?

Tags: d3.js, ssas

I worked with both Json and Xml data with d3.js API.Now, I tried to render D3.Js with OLAP data and found that CellSet is not valid format for D3.Can any one please provide me a sample to get cellset data for D3?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is more clear. Include a subject in the second sentence to disambiguate between whether you already did this, or need to do it and are running into trouble. Include program(parts) that you have and any error messages.

Comment: Question is modified

Comment: Did you find a solution ?